# Replacing even numbers with zero - Infinite loop issue in C

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I've did a program for replacing even numbers with 0 and putting them at the end of the array.

> *Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
>   Output: 1 3 5 0 0 0*

The constrains are to use only **one loop** and **two variables** apart from the array. I've did it with a while loop but for some unknown reason it loops infinitely. Could someone please clarify?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i=0,j=5;
    while(i<6){

        //Loops till the zero is swapped to the end of the array
        if(j!=5){
            arr[j] = arr[j] + arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = arr[j] - arr[j+1];
            arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[j+1];
            j++; continue;
        }

        //Checks for even number
        if(arr[i]%2==0 && arr[i]!=0){
            arr[i]==0;
            j=i;
            continue;
        }

        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger, or do you prefer not to use one?

Comment: No I didn't use a debugger

Comment: The continue skips i++.  Try changing the while loop to a for loop.

Comment: The `continue` is actually ok. If a debugger is not an option, maybe add prints?

Comment: `arr[i]==0;` doesn't do anything (try `=`)

Comment: Using simple print statements you could've found that yourself: http://ideone.com/1dukK0 Also note that your form of moving the elements to the end seems a bit complicated. Instead of "abusing" the loop to do two different things, you could've maintained a "swap to" pointer/index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is causing the infinite loop is this line:

```
arr[i]==0;
```

This doesn't update the value of `arr[i]` when `i = 1`, so `arr[1]` is always 2, and this produces that i is stuck always with the value 1. Should be an assignment no a comparison expression:

```
arr[i]=0;
```

Note: If you enable the warnings when compiling, the line in question should produce one.

Comment: That is definitely an error, but why would that cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov because it gets stuck in `i = 1` forever, since the compiler doesn't produce an error

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov because it causes the same array position to be reprocessed over and over instead of proceeding further to where `i` is incremented